# Krytron grid potential v. anode potential

Tags: electricity

While researching gas discharge tubes (penning mixtures etc.), I came across the krytron (a cold cathode triggered spark gap tube similar to a thyratron, but triggered by a positive voltage on the grid). It was described as having the trigger grid surrounding the anode, rather than the cathode. I checked other sources in case this was a miss print, & they said the same. According to a datasheet I found on Wikipedia (http://www.roehren-museum.de/pdf/KRYTRON.pdf), it takes about 250V to trigger it, while the gap to the anode inside it blocks thousands of volts until triggered. How is this possible, when the gap to the cathode appears to be larger?[image]

Also, the sprytron, (a vacuum version of it) can trigger on as little as 200V.
I assume, the K-G gap would have to be nM wide, so quantum tunneling can occur. Is this true?

Comment: There, a voltage pulse is applied to the grid.

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that the anode is the common electrode instead of the cathode. The common electrode doesn't have to be the negative as in the case of a thermionic valve, so it could be like a pnp transistor & be opposite polarity, with the grid near the positive electrode instead of the negative, & the trigger potential applied grid to anode instead of grid to cathode.